# How to add values of all columns of various .csv files keeping only single header and the first label column the same?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

So I have various .csv files in a directory of the same structure with first row as the header and first column as labels.  Say file 1 is as below:

```
name,value1,value2,value3,value4,......
name1,100,200,0,0,...
name2,101,201,0,0,...
name3,102,202,0,0,...
name4,103,203,0,0,...
....
```

File2:

```
name,value1,value2,value3,value4,......
name1,1000,2000,0,0,...
name2,1001,2001,0,0,...
name3,1002,2002,0,0,...
name4,1003,2003,0,0,...
....
```

All the .csv files have the same structure with the same number of rows and columns.

What I want is something that looks like this:

```
name,value1,value2,value3,value4,......
name1,1100,2200,0,0,...
name2,1102,2202,0,0,...
name3,1104,2204,0,0,...
name4,1103,2206,0,0,...
....
```

Where the all the value columns in the last file will be the sum of corresponding values in those columns of all the .csv files. So under value1 in the resulting file I should have 1000+100+...+... and so on.

The number of .csv files isn't fixed, so I think I'll need a loop.

How do I achieve this with a bash script on a Linux machine.
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using awk for this problem.

Comment: @Mark I know I have to use awk but not sure how to.

Comment: I have seen questions (and answers) for things similar to this, search some more.  You are trying to add values in columns using `awk`.  The first line can be extracted with `head -1 file.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `AWK`, try something like:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
    FNR==1 {header=$0}      # header line
    FNR>1 {
        sum[FNR,1] = $1     # name column
        for (j=2; j<=NF; j++) {
            sum[FNR,j] += $j
        }
    }
    END {
        print header
        for (i=2; i<=FNR; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<=NF; j++) {
                $j = sum[i,j]
            }
            print
        }
    }' *.csv
```

- It iterates over lines and columns accumulating the value into the simulated 2-dimensional array `sum`.
- You do not have to explicitly loop over csv files. AWK automatically does it
  for you.
- After reading all csv files it reports the amounts for each line and column in the `END` block.
- Note that gawk 4.0 and newer version support *true* multi-dimensional array.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

In order to calculate the *average* instead of sum, try:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
    FNR==1 {header=$0}      # header line
    FNR>1 {
        sum[FNR,1] = $1     # names column
        for (j=2; j<=NF; j++) {
            sum[FNR,j] += $j
        }
    }
    END {
        print header
        files = ARGC - 1    # number of csv files
        for (i=2; i<=FNR; i++) {
            $1 = sum[i,1]   # another treatment for the 1st column
            for (j=2; j<=NF; j++) {
                $j = sum[i,j] / files
                # if you want to specify the number of decimal places,
                # try something like:
                # $j = sprintf("%.2f", sum[i,j] / files)
            }
            print
        }
    }' *.csv
```

Comment: I have one more question though - Say I know the number of files to be 10 and I want to get the average of all the values in all the columns instead of the sum what should I change or how can I get that?                                                           An answer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: Good to know its worling. In case of caclulating the average, it will be a good idea to let the program
count the number of csv files.
The AWK built-in variable `ARGC` holds the number of command line arguments
(including the command name itself as C does) then we can know the count
of csv files by subtracting 1 from `ARGC`. I've updated my answer with
the code to get the average. Note that it does not assume the case that
any of csv files cannot be opened due to some kind of error. BR.

Comment: Could you please explain each line of your solution. Like what is FS, OFS, FNR, NF in this context. I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
/tmp> cat f1.csv
name,value1,value2,value3,value4
name1,100,200,0,0
name2,101,201,0,0
name3,102,202,0,0
name4,103,203,0,0
/tmp> cat f2.csv
name,value1,value2,value3,value4
name1,1000,2000,0,0
name2,1001,2001,0,0
name3,1002,2002,0,0
name4,1003,2003,0,0
/tmp>
/tmp> cat csv_add.ksh
perl -F, -lane '
@FH=@F  if $.==1;
if($.>1) {
         if( $F[0] ~~ @names )
        {
         @t1=@{ $kv{$F[0]} };
         for($i=0;$i<$#t1-1;$i++) { $t1[$i]+=$F[$i+1] }
         $kv{$F[0]}=[ @t1 ];
       }
        else {
        $kv{$F[0]}=[ @F[1..$#F] ];
        push(@names,$F[0]);
        }

}
END { print join(" ",@FH); for(@names) { print "$_,".join(",",@{$kv{$_}}) }}
close(ARGV) if eof
' f1.csv f2.csv
/tmp>
/tmp> csv_add.ksh
name value1 value2 value3 value4
name1,1100,2200,0,0
name2,1102,2202,0,0
name3,1104,2204,0,0
name4,1106,2206,0,0
/tmp>
```